# text file manipulation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a text file which contain a combination of string and numbers. for example like following:

*Preprint, echo=NO, model=NO, history=NO, contact=NO

*Element, type=S4R

1,   1,   9, 189,  84

2,   9,  10, 190, 189

3,  10,  11, 191, 190

4,  11,  12, 192, 191

*Surface, type=ELEMENT, name=Surf-1

I like to remove >> 2, 9, 10, 190, 189
I mean I want to have following in a new file:

*Preprint, echo=NO, model=NO, history=NO, contact=NO

*Element, type=S4R

1,   1,   9, 189,  84

3,  10,  11, 191, 190

4,  11,  12, 192, 191

*Surface, type=ELEMENT, name=Surf-1

I should notice that these data are changed, and the only thing that I know about them is its number, for above example line 4.

I have googled many times to write a text file from another one by skipping from special line that I just know its number without much success!

any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fgets` function allows you to read an ASCII file line by line. When you encounter the line you want to skip (knowing its number as you said) just use the `continue` statement to skip the iteration :

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

input = fopen('input.txt','r');
output = fopen('output.txt','w');
line = fgets(input);
fprintf(output,'%s',line);
cpt=0;
offset = 3;

while ischar(line)
    cpt=cpt+1;
    if (cpt==offset) 
        line = fgets(input);
        continue;
    end
    line = fgets(input);
    fprintf(output,'%s',line);
end

fclose(input);
fclose(output);
```

The first `fgets` allows you to copy the first line from your input file in memory.

The following `fprintf` writes it into your output file.

Next you define a counter initialized to zero and you also define the offset, that is the line you want to skip minus 1 because you have already read the first line.

Then you use a `WHILE` loop in which you read each line from the input file with the `fgets` function and directly writes it into your output file. When you reach the end of the file, `fgets` return -1 which is not a character and so the loop ends.

You notice that `cpt` is iterated and if it equals the offset then you must skip the line, so you read it but you do not write it and the `continue` statement allows you to jump to the next iteration of the loop skipping the remaining instructions.

You can use `fgetl` instead of `fgets` if you want to get rid of newline characters.

The input file :

> *Preprint, echo=NO, model=NO, history=NO, contact=NO
>
> *Element, type=S4R
>
> 1, 1, 9, 189, 84
>
> 2, 9, 10, 190, 189
>
> 3, 10, 11, 191, 190
>
> 4, 11, 12, 192, 191
>
> *Surface, type=ELEMENT, name=Surf-1

The output file :

> *Preprint, echo=NO, model=NO, history=NO, contact=NO
>
> *Element, type=S4R
>
> 1, 1, 9, 189, 84
>
> 3, 10, 11, 191, 190
>
> 4, 11, 12, 192, 191
>
> *Surface, type=ELEMENT, name=Surf-1